# Antlr ignoring characters such as ~,@,#,$,%,*,(,),{,},[,]

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

The Antlr somehow ignores the characters such as ~,@,#,$,%,*,(,),{,},[,] from the input string.

I tested the below grammar with input string's such as show~~~, show ~@#$% etc but the Antlr escapes the characters on the eclipse/antlr works interpreter. I want such scenarios to throw an exception and not to recover from them. Pls do let me know if you have faced this before and if so what did u do to get rid of it.

```
grammar Sample; 
options {language = Java;} @header {package a.b.c;} @lexer::header {package a.b.c;} 
prog: stat+ ; stat: expr ; expr: paramValueChildStructure ; 
paramValueChildStructure: ALPHANUMERIC;
ALPHANUMERIC: ('a'..'z' |'A'..'Z' | '0'..'9')+ ;
```

I tried to below option to get rid of the above issue but this gives unreachable code compile time issue in my generated lexer.java

```
OTHER      : . {throw new RuntimeException("unknown char: '" + $text + "'");};
```

Thanks,
Ashish

Comment: i resolved the issue adding this code. @lexer::members{
  public void recover(RecognitionException re){
    System.out.println("lexer memeber recover");
    throw new RuntimeException(re);
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

Look here: http://www.antlr3.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Custom+Syntax+Error+Recovery

The last paragraph before the conclusion is probably what you need:

> Other Recovery Mechanisms Within ANTLR Runtimes
>
> There is one other aspect of recovery which you may need to customize,
>   and that is what happens when a mismatch() occurs. You will see in the
>   generated code that there are lots of calls to the match() method.
>   Inspecting the default implementation (in the Java runtime) we find
>   that the match method will call the method
>   recoverFromMismatchedToken() and this in turn will try to use the
>   current Follow set stack to determine if the reason we mismatched is
>   that there was a spurious token in the input: X Y Z when we wanted
>   just X Z, or a missing token: X Z when we wanted X Y Z. If ANTLR can
>   determine, using the Follow sets, that by skipping a token, it would
>   see valid syntax, then it will consume the spurious token, report the
>   extra token, but will not raise a RecognitionException. Similarly, if
>   ANTLR can see that there is exactly one token missing from the input
>   stream, which if present, would make the syntax valid, then it will
>   manufacture this missing token, report the error, but again will not
>   raise the RecognitionException.
>
> If you want behavior that is different to this, then you can override
>   the match() method, or more likely, the recoverFromMismatchedToken()
>   method. Perhaps you do not want the spurious/missing error detection?
>   Or, as you will see from the default implementation, ANTLR will first
>   see if it can fix things by ignoring a token, then go on to see if it
>   can fix things by adding a token. However, there are some syntax
>   errors that can be recovered using either method - perhaps you want to
>   reverse the order that these strategies are tried?

Comment: The link is dead. Could you please add the relevant information to the post.